# How to transform two obserables streams

Tags: angular, merge, rxjs, observable

I have two observables `Observable<boolean>`
I want to merge the results e.g `false + false`, `false+true`, etc

```
this.loaded$.pipe(
  merge(this.loading$)
).subscribe(console.log); //`false`,`false`; `true`,`false`; etc
```

than I want to transform the stream in to single boolean observable based on condition:
if `val1+val2 == 1` - return `false`; if `val1+val2 !== 1` - return `true`;

So the question is how would you transform the `merged` observables ?

**UPDATE1:**
Tying to use `combineLatest` but got an issue:

```
combineLatest(
  this.loaded$, this.loading$,
  (val1, val2) => val1 + val2 === 1
);
```

> [ts] Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '{}' and 'boolean'.

**UPDATE2**

`.subscribe()` does not exists on `combineLatest()`

```
    combineLatest(
          this.loaded$, this.loading$,
          (val1, val2) => (val1, val2) => Number(val1) + Number(val2) === 1
        ).subscribe(); // does not work
```

> [ts] Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{},
>   number>'.

**UPDATE3:**
I found the answer to my question here [Why `combineLatest` returns OperatorFunction<{}, number>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344761/why-combinelatest-returns-operatorfunction-number)

Comment: what is the type of `this.loaded$` and `this.loading$`? Looks like one of it is giving you an object not `boolean`. Also, if it is of type `boolean`, its better to use the `&&` and `||` operator

Answer (score 2):

> [ts] Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{}, number>'.

you are getting this error as you are trying to convert output from boolean to number , if you want to change type that you need to make use of `SwitchMap`, but it takes only one observable stream at a time, as per my knowledge.

So suggest to make use of `forkjoin` as given below that will resolve your issue also.

---

as its Boolean result, you should apply logical operator ( && or ||) to get output , instead of numerical operator

```
 (val1, val2) => val1 && val2
```

---

As you already aware you are going to receive two value i.e. you have fix number of request and both need to be get completed for getting result, then you should use [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

```
async getResult()
{
    const example = await forkJoin( request1, request2).toPromise();
    const output = example [0] && example[1];
}
```

---

Not getting much what are you trying to achieve but if you want to apply `+` then you should convert you boolean to number like as below

```
 (val1, val2) => Number(val1) + Number(val2);
```

Comment: that is just two observable store selectors (`loaded$` and `loading$`), not requests so I do not really need `forkJoin` here ans yes I need to apply `+` not `&&` as in case `&&` of `||` I am not getting the result I need

Comment: just cant get it work with `forkJoin` getting both `example[0]` and `example[1]` `undefined`

Comment: the conversion seems to be working but I can't subscribe to the results, just updated the question. Any thoughts why it is returns `OperatorFunction<>` instead of `Observable<>` ?

Comment: @Abrkad - updated my portion of fork join ..have look

Comment: as I mentioned I am not doing any http requests here, I already have two obseravables which is just a selectors to my `store`, not really need the `forkJoin` part.

Comment: @Abrkad - you can use forjoin with observable also , check here https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: What I am struggling now is just cant subscribe to `combineLatest` as it returns `OperatorFunction<>` not `Observable<>`, please see my updated question.

Comment: `forkJoin(this.loaded$, this.loading$).subscribe(console.log);` does not work, not getting any values emitted doing this way.

Comment: OK i see the problem with `OperatorFunction`, thanks for clarifying that, but `forkJoin` just does not work as no values gets emitted when I am subscribing to that.

Comment: @Abrkad - if you see documentation and example forkjoin should work , but i tried it with http request till now , so not sure but example i checked on plunker link works fine ..you might missing something in case of forkjoin

Comment: I use to use `forkJoin` with http requests, works well, not sure why it is not working here just with observables, cant really see if I am missing anything here

Comment: Also I tried to take out the `Number` conversions from my `combineLatest` - `combineLatest(this.loaded$, this.loading$, (val1, val2) => val1);` still returning freaking `OperatorFunction<>`

Comment: FYI if I subscribe to my observables separately:    `this.loaded$.subscribe(console.log);this.loading$.subscribe(console.log);` - I do receive the values

Comment: Just researched a bit on `forkJoin` and seems like `forkJoin` waits for completed observable which explains why it is does not work in my case here. ref: https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/333

Comment: @Abrkad - thats the same thing i written in my answer ...that is the reason i used async/await

Comment: @Abrkad - and try combine latest like this , `const combined = combineLatest($loading1, $loading2); combined.subscribe([val1,val2]) => { console.log( val1 + ' ' + val2)} ); `

Comment: OK that is won't work for me here as we are not using `async-await` on client side due to no support in the old browsers

Comment: weird `const combined = combineLatest(this.loaded$, this.loading$);` still returning the `OperatorFunction<{}, [{}, boolean, boolean]>`, oh no even if I do this `const combined = combineLatest(this.loading$);` still getting that.

Comment: @Abrkad -- try this way const `example = await forkJoin( request1, request2);   example.subscribe([val1,val2]) => { console.log( val1 + ' ' + val2)} );`

Comment: cant use `async-await` due to lacking support in old browsers

Comment: @Abrkad -- try this way const example = await forkJoin( request1, request2); example.subscribe([val1,val2]) => { console.log( val1 + ' ' + val2)} ); ..this is without async/await

Comment: Getting error with that `[ts] 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.`

Comment: @Abrkad - write `async` in function  `async getResult()`..check answer for the same

Comment: cant use `async-await` due to lacking support in old browsers I already mentioned that like 2 times

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapXXX operators to achieve it.
For Ex:

```
this.loaded$.pipe(
  merge(this.loading$),
  map((value) =>  val > 5 ? true : false)
).subscribe(console.log); //`false`,`false`; `true`,`false`; etc
```

Comment: that wont work, this will always give you just one single value, I need to get two at the same time