# Why `combineLatest` returns OperatorFunction<{}, number>

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using `RxJS 6` I have two observables in my code

```ts
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators';

loading$: Observable<boolean>;
loaded$: Observable<boolean>;
```

*The observables are not coming from `http` request but from the `store`*

I need to combine/convert the sequences into one single observable value based on this logic:
If the sequence `true`, `true` or `false`, `false` - need to return new observable `true` otherwise need to return `false`

I tried to use `combineLatest` to achieve that:

```ts
combineLatest(
    this.loaded$, this.loading$,
    (val1, val2) => Number(val1) + Number(val2) === 1
)
```

But the problem is that my `combineLatest` returns `'OperatorFunction<>` and not `Observable<>` so I cannot subscribe.
Do you have any ideas on how to fix that? Or if there is another approach that can be taken?

UPDATE:
Seems like that is the answer to my question `import { combineLatest } from 'RxJS';`
currently testing

Comment: Did you import the `pipe`-variant of `combineLatest`?

Comment: See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md, you should move the result selector *out* of the arguments to combineLatest. Also note your current selector doesn't implement the behaviour you describe.

Comment: @Caramiriel yes I did

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With RxJS 5.5 it's most likely because you're using `combineLatest` from `rxjs/operators` while you want to use it as an Observable "creation method" which means you need to use `rxjs/observable/combineLatest`.

I mean you need to use this:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';
```

... instead of this:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

**Edit:** Since you mentioned you're using RxJS 6 you can import the static variant from `rxjs`.

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
```

If you're looking for `combineLatest` operator you have to import it like this:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: Why not importing directly from `rxjs`?

Comment: @Pengyy Because that imports the entire library https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#build-and-treeshaking

Comment: I see their recommendations here. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#howto-convert-deprecated-methods

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing I just need this

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
```